# PHP checking if variable from (POST) contains any numeric values

Tags: php

I need to check if a field contains any numeric values, if yes  - it will return the script.

This is my script

```
if ($name != null && $age != null) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z]$/", $param)) {
        echo 'You cannot use numbers for your name lol!';
        return;
    }
    if (!is_numeric($age)) {
        echo 'You must use numbers for your age!';
        return;
    }
    mysql_select_db("jony", $connectMysql);
    $sql="INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$connectMysql))
        die('MySQL problem:'.mysql_error());
        mysql_close($connectMysql);
        header('location: http://localhost/index.php.php');
} else {
    echo 'Fields are empty!';
    return;
}
```

I use this to check if field '$name' is numeric and if yes, it will return it:

```
    if (is_numeric($name)) {
        echo 'You cannot use numbers for your name lol!';
        return;
    }
```

It works fine if I ONLY put numbers in the field.

But if I include numbers + characters, it will continue the code and ignore the return.
Why is this happening? what have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Because [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) considers _lots_ of different things to be numeric strings, besides just integers. If you only want ints, use `ctype_digit()` or a regex `/^[\d]+$/`

Comment: It still does the same with ctype_digit(), no idea why.

Comment: What is up with `$param` in the first test? Where does that come from?

Comment: try with /^[a-z]+$/ instead of /^[a-z]$/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it for example in that way:

```
if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$name)){ 
     echo 'You cannot use numbers for your name lol!';
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test it [here](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

try with

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $name);
```

instead of

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]$/', $name);
```